# JCR (JackRabbit) Query returning empty results

Tags: java, rest, jcr, jackrabbit, magnolia

I am using magnolia for one of my project and in that I have created a REST Endpoint. The rest endpoint will read the nodes from my custom workspace and return the result to client. It is very simple.

If I run the below query in magnolia JCR Utils query app it is working fine and returning the correct results.

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:contentIndex]
```

Below is a screenshot

http://s1.postimg.org/gl59arw2n/correct_result.png

If I run the below code in my REST ENDPOINT Handler it is returning empty result set.

```
    // Get JCR session for "dinnacoDriven" workspace
    try {
        Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("dinnacoDriven");
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM [mgnl:contentIndex]");
        System.out.println(queryBuilder.toString());
        Query query = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), Query.JCR_SQL2);
        List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        NodeIterator iterator = query.execute().getNodes();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("next node");
            Node node = iterator.nextNode();
            suggestions.add(node.getProperty("title").getString());
        }
        return suggestions;
    } catch(RepositoryException ex) {
        throw new ServiceException("Internal Server Error", ex);
    }
```

I can see in the logs that `System.out.println(queryString.toString());` will print the exact same query that I am running above but `next node` will never get printed. It is returning empty results.

Its been 12 hours since I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this code, but I can't find anything.

What is problem with my code ? Why it is returning empty result set ?

EDIT:
Adding some additional information.
When I am accessing from code, I am not logged in. I am accessing anonymously.

The contentIndex nodes are stored in dinnacoDriven workspace under root node contentIndex.

Some more information, I exported the dinnacoDriven workspace into xml, this is the xml file

https://gist.github.com/riteshsangwan/efe93ee4c5077236c0c0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough data, so just wild guess: When executing query in admin central, you are logged in and has access to the nodes. When running against REST endpoint, you are not logged in and anonymous user doesn't have assigned access to `dinnacoDriven` workspace.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Ok, yes this might be the case, but isn't it supposed to throw some authorization exception instead of returning empty result set.

Comment: Thanks @Jan this was indeed the problem. But this query I want to run as anonymous user. There are two options one is to execute query in admin context and other is to add dinnacoDriven workspace read/write permission to anonymous user ( this I can do from web but I want to do it while module is being installed). Can you point to examples of both of these.

Comment: Personally, I would not give anonymous write access. That's just asking for troubles. Preferably you want to execute this in system context. As for examples, check documentation or Magnolia forum, can't think of any link from top of my head, but should be as simple as calling MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(new Op() { ... });